# enabling p5.js camera access in chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions, camera, p5.js

I am trying to make a pop up chrome extension using this face detector example made with p5.js from https://github.com/stc/face-tracking-p5js/tree/master/008_emotion example. However, when added to the extension, the pop up does not seem to be getting any camera data. The graphics show, but the face tracking data doesn't. Is this because there are issues with accessing the browser camera? It runs when not made into an extension. I have tried using other p5 camera examples and they don't load as well, so it's definitely a camera permissions thing...

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name": "Smile",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":[
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],



    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "ct.png",
        "default_popup" : "smile/index.html",
        "default_title": "Smile Count:"
        }
```

Let me know what I can do, thank you!

Comment: The popup is a separate window with its own devtools. First you should identify the problem. Right-click inside the popup, then click "inspect", then use devtools to debug the code.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I decided to use face-api and it worked :)